# DD4T Template in SDL Web 8.5 Page Returning Null Value

Tags: dd4t, web8.5, mvc

1. SDL Web 8.5 Using DD4T Template Publishing to broker DB its
   working fine. URL and Page Content exist in relavant tables. By the
   timing we published into HTML file.
2. Visual studio 2015 we created published to IIS in .Net application.
   Below setup added in Visual Studio
   solution.(DD4T.MVC5.2.2.4,DD4T.DI.Autofac.2.2.3,DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8.5.CIL.2.2.2)
3. Whenever creating Views in solution under TridionPage folder same
   name using which we used in Page Template Metadata.
4. After trying access to the page but throwing error. "The resource
   you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is
   temporarily unavailable"
5. When we tracking failed request tracing its showing attached error
   file.[image]

Kindly appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you checked you're CIL/CIS logs?

Comment: share your web app web.config using https://pastebin.com?

Comment: Web Config URL https://pastebin.com/xDDSM6pi

Comment: @ThoufikAhamed, web.config looks fine to me, I was suspecting your Global.asax.cs / PageController class ContainerBuilder and RegisterControllers stuffs something wrong, could you please update your question to share your Global.asax.cs and PageController class file

Comment: @Velmurugan Kindly find requested file from this link https://pastebin.com/8ATphS8M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue in your **Global.ascx.cs** file, The following below line wrong, it should register your **PageController** class not **MvcApplication** class

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

Corrected **Global.ascx.cs** file

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    ILifetimeScope BuildContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(PageController).Assembly);
        builder.UseDD4T();
        return builder.Build();
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var builder = BuildContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder));

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

In DD4T 2 - Instead of **TridionControllerBase** you can also use **ModelControllerBase** for View Model Build using ViewModelFactory

```
public class PageController : ModelControllerBase
{

    public PageController(IPageFactory pageFactory, IComponentPresentationFactory componentPresentationFactory,
    ILogger logger, IDD4TConfiguration config, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
        : base(pageFactory, componentPresentationFactory, logger, config, viewModelFactory)
    {

    }

    public ActionResult Page(string url)
    {
        url = !url.StartsWith("/") ? "/" + url : url;

        IPage page = GetPage(url);
        if (page == null) { 

            //TODO return 404 not found page
        }

        var pageViewModel = ViewModelFactory.BuildViewModel(page);

        return View(GetViewName(page), pageViewModel);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps to fix your issue.